# большая буква обтекает абзац

Tags: html, css

помогите сделать букву как на изображении
[image: буква абзаца]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

примерно так:

```
p:first-letter{color:red; font-size:50px; display:block; float:left; margin:0 5px 5px 0;}
```